# Login security tutorial

Tags: php, authentication

I have followed a tutorial here: http://www.phpeasystep.com/phptu/6.html
and I was just wondering if that is the best way to create a secure login area.

The part where it says

```
if(!session_is_registered(myusername)){
   header("location:main_login.php");
}
```

so it is basically one if statement from letting people in and it even visits the page where it is to login which just doesn't seem too secure to me idk.

Any light anyone can shed on this. Maybe a better tutorial that covers security better.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No; That tutorial has major problems and you should not use it.

- It stores passwords in plain text
- It uses the obsolete mysql extension (it should use at least mysqli)
- As Darren said, it's using obsolete PHP functions

The Wikihow one is a little better; it at least uses SHA-512 for password hashing, but it's still not a great login solution. The [PHP Login project](http://www.php-login.net) is a far better and more complete example to either use or follow as an example.

Comment: That Login Project seems like it is very comprehensive. If I were to implement that how safe can I say the data behind the login is safe to the client? Is the login the only thing I need to consider when protecting data behind a login screen?

Thanks

Comment: The login project uses a good hash function (via the standard PHP standard `password_hash`) - though `scrypt` is even better and avaialable as a PHP extension. The key thing about using a decent hash with salt is that compromise of one password does not help an attacker crack any other password on the system, which is definitely something that you tell your client with reasonable confidence. Authentication isn't the end of the story though - you then need to authorise what functions they are allowed to do after login - not everyone gets to be an admin!

Answer (score 0):

Where do I start.

`session_is_registered()` **is** depreciated. [<sup>[*Source*]</sup>](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-is-registered.php)

> WARNING: This function has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 5.3.0 and REMOVED
>   as of PHP 5.4.0.

You'd have to register your sessions properly like this:

```
session_start();

//.....do processing and whatever
// set session variables etc.
$_SESSION['uid'] = $uid;
```

And test for the presence like this:

```
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['uid'])) {
    header("location:main_login.php");
}
```

---

**NOTE**

You are required to have [`session_start()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php) before trying to access any `$_SESSION` information otherwise it will always return false.